# How show results in another column via "Foreach"?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I want to display more results in another column via foreach from the database but I can't get it to work.

```
<div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <?php
                        if (is_array($results))
                        {
                        foreach ($results as $data) { ?>
                        <!-- User item starts -->
                        <div class="user-item">
                            <!-- User action buttons -->
                            <div class="user-btns">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-green btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-red btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Image -->
                            <img src="<?php echo $data->avatar ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                            <!-- User details -->
                            <div class="u-details">
                                <h5><i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php echo $data->first_name . ' ' . $data->last_name ?></h5>
                                <h5><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <?php echo $data->email ?></h5>
                                <h5><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> <?php echo $data->username ?></h5>

                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- User item ends -->
                        <?php } } ?>


                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <?php
                        if (is_array($results))
                        {
                            foreach ($results as $data) { ?>
                                <!-- User item starts -->
                                <div class="user-item">
                                    <!-- User action buttons -->
                                    <div class="user-btns">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-green btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-red btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Image -->
                                    <img src="<?php echo $data->avatar ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                    <!-- User details -->
                                    <div class="u-details">
                                        <h5><i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php echo $data->first_name . ' ' . $data->last_name ?></h5>
                                        <h5><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <?php echo $data->email ?></h5>
                                        <h5><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> <?php echo $data->username ?></h5>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- User item ends -->
                            <?php } } ?>

                    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's two different columns. I want to do foreach and show one set of information in one column and the other set in another. However, the code below returns the same value in both columns.

how can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: What is for your one set? Can you explain which output you expected?

Comment: Okay, so this is what I want: http://gyazo.com/13a832df1651ee6ec7bfc7675b1b349d -

I want the name to be displayed in another column with the foreach thing but I dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through each item of results in both loops, so their results are the same.  Why not try something like this

```
<?php
$cols = 3;
?>
<div class="row">
        <?php
        if (is_array($results))
        {
            for($i = 0 ; $i < $cols ; $i++)
            {
                echo "
                <div class='col-md-".(12/$cols)."'>";
                for ($j = 0 ; $j < (count($results) / $cols) + 1 ; $j++)
                {
                    if ($i * $cols + $j < count($results)) // make sure it won't give errors for array out of range....
                    {
                        echo "
                        <div class='user-item'>
                            <div class='user-btns'>
                            <a href='#' class='btn btn-green btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a>
                            <a href='#' class='btn btn-red btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <img src='".$results[$i* $cols + $j]->avatar."' alt=' class='img-responsive'/>
                        <div class='u-details'>
                            <h5><i class='fa fa-user'></i>".$results[$i* $cols + $j]->first_name . ' ' . $results[$i* $cols + $j]->last_name."</h5>
                            <h5><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>".$results[$i* $cols + $j]->email."</h5>
                            <h5><i class='fa fa-user-md'></i>".$results[$i * $cols + $j]->username."</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class='clearfix'></div>";
                    }
                }
                echo "
                </div>";
            }
        }
        ?>

</div>
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I have an extra row, how would I add this into the extra row so that the third row displays the other 3 results? Thanks.

Comment: i edited the code to give 1 more result on the first column. not sure if this was you meant - did you confuse rows with columns?

Comment: I'm sorry for any confusion, I mean columns, sorry. With the code you gave, I can only display 2 columns of informaiton. I wnat to display it in the third column as well. 

THanks :)

Comment: ok, changed as requested . hopefully the changed should give you an idea on how to generalise the problem.  the code was not tested but the idea should work even if there were some syntax errors etc.